# Single SELECT each time its called

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I'm trying to make record by record inserts into TableA with values from TableB by using this query:

```sql
SELECT id_user FROM utilizador WHERE id_perfil = '4'
```

This query gives me a column with all the different `id_user`s, but I only want one `id_user` each time the query runs.

Is there a way for `SELECT` to only give me one `id_user` and have it give me the next  `id_user` when I run it again?

Comment: which db you are really using  ..

Comment: Microsoft SQL Management Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be using `NOT EXISTS` :

```
INSERT INTO tableA(id_perfil)
SELECT TOP id_user 
  FROM utilizador u
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 0 FROM tableA WHERE id_perfil = u.id_user )
```

P.S. Seems like `utilizador` is `TableB`